# Can I add badge id to apple wallet

Tags: ios, swift, wallet, apple-wallet

I’m working on application that contains the employee Badge card
Can I add this card to wallet ? To use NFC to get the access for inter the company

Answer (score 1):

You would first need to get an [NFC certificate for Apple](https://developer.apple.com/contact/passkit/).  Access isn't currently one of their use cases, so if applying, I would suggest listing the principle reason as transactional (E.g. canteen, or other cases where the pass could be used for payment).

You would then need to configure your access hardware to be compatible with the Apple VAS protocol.  There are very few solutions available, but you might want to take a look at [VTAP100](https://vtap100.com).